# I ported code from FreeBSD to Linux but it doesn't extract destination address

Tags: c, linux, sockets, ip-address, freebsd

This C code extracts source and destination IPv4 addresses on a FreeBSD system from a socket. I ported it to Linux and it works only partially. It prints the source address of the pk correctly but not the destination address of the pk (which would be the IP address of my machine). I always get a destination address of `0.0.0.0`.

How do I change the code to make it also extract/print the destination address?

```
static void* start_controlpackets_demuxer_ipv4(void* arg) {
    int r;

    struct addrinfo hints;
    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

    struct addrinfo* sorter_addr;
    r = getaddrinfo(NULL, LISP_CONTROL_PORT, &hints, &sorter_addr);
    if (r != 0) {
        fatalr("Unable to get westbound IPv4 listener address", r);
    }

    struct addrinfo* curr_addr;
    int s;
    for (curr_addr = sorter_addr; curr_addr != NULL; curr_addr = curr_addr->ai_next) {
        s = socket(curr_addr->ai_family, curr_addr->ai_socktype, curr_addr->ai_protocol);
        if (s == -1) {
            continue;
        }

        r = bind(s, curr_addr->ai_addr, curr_addr->ai_addrlen);
        if (r == -1) {
            continue;
        }

        freeaddrinfo(sorter_addr);
        break;
    }

    if (curr_addr == NULL) {
        fatal("Unable to bind westbound IPv4 listener");
    }

    ipv4_controlpackets_socket = s;

    debug_printf("IPv4 westbound server is listening");

    /*
     * The datagram is kept in the stack space. Should the processing be offloaded to a pool of worker threads,
     * it will be necessary to move it to the heap.
     */
    uint8_t buf[IP_MAXLEN];
    char control_buf[SOCK_MSG_CONTROL_LEN];

    int opt = 1;
    setsockopt(s, IPPROTO_IP, IP_RECVDSTADDR, &opt, sizeof(opt));

    while (1) {
        ipv4_datagram datagram;
        datagram.payload = buf;

        struct msghdr raw_msg;
        struct iovec iov;

        raw_msg.msg_name = &(datagram.source);
        raw_msg.msg_namelen = sizeof(datagram.source);
        raw_msg.msg_iov = &iov;
        raw_msg.msg_iovlen = 1;
        raw_msg.msg_iov->iov_base = datagram.payload;
        raw_msg.msg_iov->iov_len = IP_MAXLEN;
        raw_msg.msg_control = (caddr_t) &control_buf;
        raw_msg.msg_controllen = SOCK_MSG_CONTROL_LEN;
        raw_msg.msg_flags = 0;

        datagram.payload_len = recvmsg(s, &raw_msg, 0);

        if (datagram.payload_len < 0) {
            fatal("Error reading from westbound IPv4 socket");
        }

        for (struct cmsghdr *c = CMSG_FIRSTHDR(&raw_msg); c != NULL; c = CMSG_NXTHDR(&raw_msg, c)) {
            if (c->cmsg_level != IPPROTO_IP || c->cmsg_type != IP_RECVDSTADDR) {
                continue;
            }

            struct in_addr* tmp_destination = (struct in_addr*) CMSG_DATA(c);

            memset(&(datagram.destination), 0, sizeof(datagram.destination));
#ifndef LINUX_OS
            datagram.destination.sin_len = sizeof(datagram.destination);
#endif
            datagram.destination.sin_family = AF_INET;
            datagram.destination.sin_addr = *tmp_destination;
        }

        char src[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
        inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(datagram.source.sin_addr), src, INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
        char dst[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
        inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(datagram.destination.sin_addr), dst, INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
        debug_printf("Processing UDPv4 datagram from %s to %s", src, dst);

        process_ipv4_datagram(&datagram);
    }

    pthread_exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Where did you get `IP_RECVDSTADDR` from? AFAIK, it is a BSD/Darwin-only feature. [`IP_RECVORIGDSTADDR`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ip.7.html) is what's used in Linux. I could probably whip up a Linux example, if you'll verify the code also works in FreeBSD.

Comment: Your right, IP_RECVDSTADDR is for BSD. The code that i posted indeed works on FreeBSD but i need to make in work on Linux. So changed to IP_RECVORIGDSTADDR as u suggested but still it doesnt work.

Comment: The socket option is `IP_RECVORIGDSTADDR` and the ancillary message type is `IP_ORIGDSTADDR` in Linux, not `IP_RECVDSTADDR`. You're also supposed to use the `CMSG_()` macros. See my (lightly tested to work) example code in my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Linux, the socket option is [`IP_RECVORIGDSTADDR`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ip.7.html). (Your code fails to initialize `iov` as well.)

Here is a lightly-tested example that works in Linux (if using 2.6.29, 3.x, or later kernel).

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>


typedef struct {
    struct sockaddr_in  source;
    struct sockaddr_in  destination;
    uint8_t            *payload;
    int                 payload_len;        
} ipv4_datagram;

void process_ipv4_datagram(ipv4_datagram *const datagram)
{
    char  src_host[128], src_port[32];
    char  dst_host[128], dst_port[32];
    int   result, i;

    src_host[0] = src_port[0] = '\0';
    dst_host[0] = dst_port[0] = '\0';

    result = getnameinfo((const struct sockaddr *)(&datagram->source),
                         sizeof (struct sockaddr_in),
                         src_host, sizeof src_host,
                         src_port, sizeof src_port,
                         NI_NUMERICHOST | NI_NUMERICSERV);
    if (result) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Warning: Cannot translate source address: %s.\n", gai_strerror(result));
        fflush(stderr);
    }

    result = getnameinfo((const struct sockaddr *)(&datagram->destination),
                         sizeof (struct sockaddr_in),
                         dst_host, sizeof dst_host,
                         dst_port, sizeof dst_port,
                         NI_NUMERICHOST | NI_NUMERICSERV);
    if (result) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Warning: Cannot translate destination address: %s.\n", gai_strerror(result));
        fflush(stderr);
    }

    printf("Received %d bytes,\n", datagram->payload_len);
    printf("  From %s port %s\n", src_host, src_port);
    printf("    To %s port %s", dst_host, dst_port);
    for (i = 0; i < datagram->payload_len; i++)
        if (i & 15)
            printf(" %02x", datagram->payload[i]);
        else
            printf("\n\t%02x", datagram->payload[i]);
    printf("\n");
    fflush(stdout);
}

static volatile sig_atomic_t  done = 0;

static void handle_done(int signum)
{
    __sync_bool_compare_and_swap(&done, (sig_atomic_t)0, (sig_atomic_t)signum);
}

static int install_done(int signum)
{
    struct sigaction act;
    memset(&act, 0, sizeof act);
    sigemptyset(&act.sa_mask);
    act.sa_handler = handle_done;
    act.sa_flags = 0;
    if (sigaction(signum, &act, NULL) == -1)
        return errno;
    return 0;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int socketfd = -1;

    /* Verify command line parameters, and print usage if necessary.
    */
    if (argc < 2 || argc > 3 || !strcmp(argv[1], "-h") || !strcmp(argv[1], "--help")) {
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [ -h | --help ]\n", argv[0]);
        fprintf(stderr, "       %s [ ADDRESS/HOST ] PORT\n", argv[0]);
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "This listens on IPv4 UDP connections, and reports on them.\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "Send INT (Ctrl+C), HUP, or TERM signal to exit.\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /* Install INT, TERM, and HUP signal handlers.
     * They all set the 'done' flag if caught.
    */
    if (install_done(SIGINT) ||
        install_done(SIGTERM) ||
        install_done(SIGHUP)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot install signal handlers: %s.\n", strerror(errno));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /* Open the listening socket. */
    {
        struct addrinfo *list = NULL, *curr, hints; 
        const char *node, *serv;
        int result;

        /* Empty or "-" or "*" address is the wildcard address. */
        if (argc == 3) {
            node = argv[1];
            serv = argv[2];
            if (node[0] == '\0' || !strcmp(node, "-") || !strcmp(node, "*"))
                node = NULL;
        } else {
            node = NULL;
            serv = argv[1];
        }

        memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
        hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
        hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM;
        hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;
        hints.ai_protocol = 0;
        hints.ai_canonname = NULL;
        hints.ai_addr = NULL;
        hints.ai_next = NULL;
        result = getaddrinfo(node, serv, &hints, &list);
        if (result) {
            if (node)
                fprintf(stderr, "%s %s: %s.\n", node, serv, gai_strerror(result));
            else
                fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s.\n", serv, gai_strerror(result));
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        result = 0;
        socketfd = -1;
        for (curr = list; curr != NULL; curr = curr->ai_next) {
            socketfd = socket(curr->ai_family, curr->ai_socktype, curr->ai_protocol);
            if (socketfd == -1)
                continue;

            if (bind(socketfd, curr->ai_addr, curr->ai_addrlen) == 0)
                break;

            result = errno;
            close(socketfd);
            socketfd = -1;
        }

        freeaddrinfo(list);

        if (socketfd == -1) {
            if (result)
                fprintf(stderr, "%s.\n", strerror(result));
            else
                fprintf(stderr, "Cannot bind to socket.\n");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }

    /* Enable the IP_RECVORIGDSTADDR socket option. */
    {
        int flag = 1;
        if (setsockopt(socketfd, IPPROTO_IP, IP_RECVORIGDSTADDR, &flag, sizeof flag) == -1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "IP_RECVORIGDSTADDR not supported: %s.\n", strerror(errno));
            close(socketfd);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }

    /* Receive datagram messages, until signaled.
     * Note that signal delivery causes recvmsg() to return with -1, errno == EINTR.
    */
    while (!done) {
        char    data_buffer[1024];
        char    ancillary_buffer[1024];
        ssize_t data_bytes;

        ipv4_datagram   dgram;
        struct msghdr   msg;
        struct iovec    iov;
        struct cmsghdr *cmsg;

        iov.iov_base = data_buffer;
        iov.iov_len = sizeof data_buffer;

        msg.msg_name = &(dgram.source);
        msg.msg_namelen = sizeof dgram.source;
        msg.msg_iov = &iov;
        msg.msg_iovlen = 1;
        msg.msg_control = ancillary_buffer;
        msg.msg_controllen = sizeof ancillary_buffer;
        msg.msg_flags = 0;

        memset(&(dgram.source), 0, sizeof dgram.source);
        memset(&(dgram.destination), 0, sizeof dgram.destination);

        data_bytes = recvmsg(socketfd, &msg, 0);
        if (data_bytes == (ssize_t)-1) {

            /* Interrupted by a signal? */
            if (errno == EINTR)
                continue;

            /* Other errors we can ignore? */
            if (errno == EAGAIN || errno == EWOULDBLOCK ||
                errno == ECONNREFUSED)
                continue;

            fprintf(stderr, "Error receiving data: %s.\n", strerror(errno));
            fflush(stderr);
            break;
        }

        dgram.payload = (void *)data_buffer;
        dgram.payload_len = data_bytes;

        /* Find IP_ORIGDSTADDR ancillary message. */
        for (cmsg = CMSG_FIRSTHDR(&msg); cmsg != NULL; cmsg = CMSG_NXTHDR(&msg, cmsg))
            if (cmsg->cmsg_level == IPPROTO_IP &&
                cmsg->cmsg_type == IP_ORIGDSTADDR)
                memmove(&dgram.destination, CMSG_DATA(cmsg), sizeof dgram.destination);

        process_ipv4_datagram(&dgram);
    }

    close(socketfd);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

This is an edited version to illustrate the use of the desired `ipv4_datagram` structure and `process_ipv4_datagram()` function.

Compile it using e.g.

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -O2 example.c -o example
```

If you run e.g.

```
./example host port
```

you can use Ctrl+C to instruct it to exit cleanly.
Use e.g. netcat to test connections (from other machines on the same local network) using e.g.

```
date | nc -q 1 -u host port
```

Comment: This is exactly what i needed. it works. thanks a lot!

Comment: just a last question. i need to pass on a datagram which has this structure: 
typedef struct {
 struct sockaddr_in source;
 struct sockaddr_in destination;
 uint8_t* payload;
 int payload_len;
} ipv4_datagram; 
-- how can i pass the information that (thanks to you) i just extracted to a ipv4_datagram datagram? because there will be another function that proccess ipv4_datagrams. its called at the end of my original code: process_ipv4_datagram(&datagram);

Comment: @Pheonix7: The `payload` member needs to point to the data buffer the `iov` references, the `payload_len` member is the return value from `recvmsg()`, the `msg.name` and `msg.name_len` should point to `source` in the `ipv4_datagram` structure, and the `destination` is copied from the ancillary buffer in the `CMSG()` for loop. I modified the above example code to make these explicit.

Answer (score 0):

Check the cmsg_len field. According to the recv(2) man page it doesn't return an address in case of a local error.

Comment: can you show me a code snipet that does this check and prints the error?

Comment: `if (!cmsg->cmsg_len) { /* handle error here... */ }`
Have a look at the man page recv(2) for further details.